# FireMonkey Mobile: incorrect form open

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, delphi-xe, firemonkey, delphi-xe5

```
procedure TForm.FormResize(Sender: TObject);
begin
Application.FormFactor.Orientations := [TFormOrientation.Landscape];
end;
```

The form opens in width, all is well. But if it is collapsed and expanded, then there are glitches (screenshot), shape becomes distorted, as if the port first and then LANDSCAPE. (black zone it's my application)

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jGm1o.png]